# Touch button to use soft keyboard edit EditText no response when type number -- Android 4.2

Tags: android, android-layout

In my project customer want use an Editbutton to use soft keyboard to change the `EditText`.  when It can work well when type the letter, but no response when type number. My device is android 4.2 and also can't work on android 4.0.

**code:**

```
public ImageButton backBtn;
Button domestic_Renamebtn1;
Button domestic_Renamebtn2;
EditText domestic_EditText1;
EditText domestic_EditText2;
private InputMethodManager imm;
TextView timeView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    timeView  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Hello);
    domestic_Renamebtn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.User1_Edit1);
    domestic_Renamebtn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.User1_Edit2);
    domestic_EditText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.User1_EditText1);
    domestic_EditText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.User1_EditText2);

    domestic_EditText1.setEnabled(false);
    domestic_EditText1.setFocusable(false);
    domestic_EditText1.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    domestic_EditText2.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE); 

    domestic_EditText2.setEnabled(false);
    domestic_EditText2.setFocusable(false);
    domestic_EditText2.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    domestic_EditText2.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE); 

    imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(domestic_EditText1.getWindowToken(), 0);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(domestic_EditText2.getWindowToken(), 0);



    domestic_Renamebtn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            domestic_EditText1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            domestic_EditText1.setEnabled(true);                
            domestic_EditText1.setFocusable(true);
            domestic_EditText1.setActivated(true);
            domestic_EditText1.setText("");
            imm.showSoftInput(domestic_EditText1, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);

        }
    });


    domestic_EditText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            domestic_EditText1.setEnabled(false);
            domestic_EditText1.setFocusable(false);
            domestic_EditText1.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            domestic_EditText1.setActivated(false);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(domestic_EditText1.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    });

    domestic_Renamebtn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            domestic_EditText2.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            domestic_EditText2.setEnabled(true);                
            domestic_EditText2.setFocusable(true);
            domestic_EditText2.setActivated(true);
            domestic_EditText2.setText("");
            imm.showSoftInput(domestic_EditText2, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);

        }
    });


    domestic_EditText2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            domestic_EditText2.setEnabled(false);
            domestic_EditText2.setFocusable(false);
            domestic_EditText2.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            domestic_EditText2.setActivated(false);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(domestic_EditText2.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    });
    ;

    domestic_EditText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        String str;
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String s = arg0.toString();
            if(s.indexOf("\n") >= 0){
                domestic_EditText1.setText(str);
                domestic_EditText1.setEnabled(false);
                domestic_EditText1.setFocusable(false);
                domestic_EditText1.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                domestic_EditText1.setActivated(false);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(domestic_EditText1.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            str = arg0.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    domestic_EditText2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        String str;
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String s = arg0.toString();
            if(s.indexOf("\n") >= 0){
                domestic_EditText2.setText(str);
                domestic_EditText2.setEnabled(false);
                domestic_EditText2.setFocusable(false);
                domestic_EditText2.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                domestic_EditText2.setActivated(false);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(domestic_EditText2.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            str = arg0.toString();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView android:id="@+id/Hello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/User1_EditText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="Joe Bloggs"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#707070"
    android:textSize="32sp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/User1_Edit1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="Edit1"/>


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/User1_EditText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:text="****"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#707070"
    android:textSize="32sp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/User1_Edit2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Edit2" />
```